# How many cells of each cell type are there in C.elegans?

Tags: zoology, development

C.elegans is a very well studied organism. Of its approximately 1000 cells in the adult stage, how many of each cell type are there? The only information I could grab from the internet (wormatlas.org) is that there are about 300 neurons. What about the rest of the cells? An answer for other simple animals such as sponges, planaria, jellyfish etc., even in relative proportion of cells, would be accepted.

(I appreciate that this question is somewhat broad and unspecific: eg. are all neurons of the same type? (Yes) Are germ cells included? (No, because they vary) Please ignore such niceties.)

Edit: To clarify, the question asks for a breakdown of the cells along the lines of:
Neurons 300 cells, Epithelium 200 cells, etc., Total 1000 cells

Comment: I guess you didn't find [this page](http://www.wormatlas.org/celllist.htm), then? I'm not a worm biologist, so how did I find such information? I googled `list of c elegans cell types`. **PLEASE** do your own research before asking here.

Comment: @MattDMo You should make an answer out of the link you post. An answer as simple as `There are about n types of cell (see here)` would be enough.

Comment: The cell map of *C.elegans* is well known.

Comment: Sorry, did I ask "How many cell types are there in C.elegans?" No I did NOT want a list of cell types. PLEASE read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: -1 and VTC because this question is unclear (what exact do you define as a "cell type"?) and easily answerable yourself once you have a clear definition.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @MattDMo comment...

There are about 17 cell types in hermaphrodites *C. elegans* (see [here](http://www.wormatlas.org/celllist.htm)). However, it varies very much depending how you count. You might want to have a look at  [Sulston and White (1988)](http://cshmonographs.org/index.php/monographs/issue/view/087969307.17).

Comment: Actually http://www.wormatlas.org/celllistsulston.htm is probably closer to what OP is after, although the whole site is highly relevant.